# Program crashing for unknown reason

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, crash, segue

I can not figure out why this error is happening. I have been on it for days now.
I have a VC called ADViewController this displays a question from a plist file. It has its own class and is a subclass of ViewController not UIViewController(This may be worth mentioning). I am having difficultly performing the Segue "LevelCleared" which is its own class ClearedAd1ViewController. I apologize if this is a stupid question but I can not figure it out myself. 
This is ADViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
rootArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Addition1" ofType:@"plist"]];
currentQuestion = -1;
[self showNextQuestion];

}
-(void) showNextQuestion{
currentQuestion++;
if (currentQuestion <= 2) {

    int numItems = [rootArray count];
    NSMutableArray *question = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *A = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *B = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *C = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *addimage = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *Answer = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];


    for (NSDictionary *itemData in rootArray) {
        [question addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"question"]];
        [A addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"A"]];
        [B addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"B"]];
        [C addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"C"]];
        [addimage addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"ImageUse"]];
        [Answer addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"ANS"]];

    }
    self.questionasked.text = question[currentQuestion];
    self.answer1.text = A[currentQuestion];
    self.answer2.text = B[currentQuestion];
    self.answer3.text = C[currentQuestion];
    additionImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:addimage[currentQuestion]];
    self.correctAns = Answer[currentQuestion];}
else{
    NSLog(@"End of Array ");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LevelCleared" sender:nil];

}
}
```

I will write the NSLog message to the console but will not perform the Segue. When it reaches the 3rd item in the array I want to perform a segue but I keep getting this error

```
 2013-03-30 16:37:15.912 thefyp[1268:c07] End of Array 
2013-03-30 16:37:15.915 thefyp[1268:c07] -[ClearedAd1ViewController setCurrentQuestion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x757fcd0
2013-03-30 16:37:15.916 thefyp[1268:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ClearedAd1ViewController setCurrentQuestion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x757fcd0'
***First throw call stack:
 (0x1cb8012 0x10f5e7e 0x1d434bd 0x1ca7bbc 0x1ca794e 0x834b 0x481b87 0x11bdd2 0x8f87 0x9050 0x1109705 0x3d2c0 0x3d258 0xfe021 0xfe57f 0xfd6e8 0x6ccef 0x6cf02 0x4ad4a 0x3c698 0x1c13df9 0x1c13ad0 0x1c2dbf5 0x1c2d962 0x1c5ebb6 0x1c5df44 0x1c5de1b 0x1c127e3 0x1c12668 0x39ffc 0x2a8d 0x29b5 0x1)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

(lldb)

Comment: You have got your concepts all wrong. I won't venture into that in this post. `ClearedAd1ViewController` does not implement `setCurrentQuestion:`.

Comment: Check your `ClearedAd1ViewController.m` file. The method `setCurrentQuestion:` hasn't been implemented.

Comment: So do I declare a method `setCurrentQuestion` in ClearedAd1ViewController.m ? And what exactly is to go inside that method?

Comment: All I want to do is perform that segue when the current question is equal to 2????

Comment: As I said, you have your concepts all wrong. Explaining this to you is out of the scope of StackOverflow. Please read some beginner tutorials and the documentation to learn more. You are calling `setCurrentQuestion:` somewhere in your code, but `ClearedAd1ViewController` doesn't implement it.

Comment: @duci9y actually there is a method setCurrentQuestion: in ClearedAd1ViewController if currentQuestion is synthsized object. because xCode creates this method and defines it when you create property and synthized

Comment: Maybe it is spelled incorrectly, or there is a difference in the case. Check your code or post it here for those interested to look into.

Comment: Does `ADViewController.m` have a `prepareForSegue:`? If it does can you post it. Also, can you post `ClearedAd1ViewController.h` and `ClearedAd1ViewController.m`?

Comment: @Sfocker as i look your code and understand you try to change the currentQuestion value in ClearedAd1ViewController but this property is not belong to ClearedAd1ViewController(as i guess you try to make it -1 again for next turn).

Comment: I just did a search through the code but I knew there wasnt there is no `setCurrentQuestion` anywhere. Is there some how I can post the project here if those of you who wish to look at it can

Answer (score 0):

I think you are terribly confused I think what your trying to say is that ADViewController is a subclass of UIView not a ViewController class. In which case

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LevelCleared" sender:nil];
```

cannot be called as it is a view controller method not a UIView method.
this is why the error says the selector  is recognized.

Therefore you need to implement your code within a UIView controller to fix this problem.

Comment: Many thanks for your response . This is the ADViewController.h
`@interface LevelAViewController : ViewController`
So should this read 
`@interface LevelAViewController : UIViewController`

Comment: Yes it should. I would recommend making a new class of type UIViewController and then place your code into there. Make sure any errors from moving your code over are fixed and then finally check that you have correctly set the identifier as LevelCleared in interface builder.

Comment: Wow it still does not appear to be working `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setCurrentQuestion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71c4e90'`

Comment: try setting the sender to self.

Comment: I am afraid not...I really don't know! Is there anyway I could send you the project! Perhaps there is something I am missing

Comment: Wait is there a method called setCurrentQuestion in ClearedAd1ViewController.  if so is it called when the new view controller is loaded? can you show me the code for it?

Comment: No there isnt! This is the thing I am having trouble understanding at no point in my code ANYWHERE does it say `setCurrentQuestion`

Comment: ok email the code to jamespickup10@gmail.com and Ill have a quick look.

Comment: I have had a look through your code and have to say I am completely baffled as to why it doesn't work. The only way setCurrent question would be called is via: currentQuestion = something; however that doesn't happen. I'm afraid I can't help you any further sorry.